# Display file name after using uigetfile

Tags: matlab, filenames, msgbox

I have a question. I'm using Matlab. I use uigetfile and after user select the text file, I want to display the file name in a message box (and without path name). How can I do that? This is the example of my code.

```
[HMF,HMP,HML] = uigetfile(('*.txt', 'Please select your data');

if HML>0;

msgbox([You selected 'bla3']) <- I know this isn't correct)

else

return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the file name as first output argument of `uigetfile`. Thus, all you need to do is:

```
[HMF,HMP,HML] = uigetfile(('*.txt', 'Please select your data');

if HML>0;

msgbox(sprintf('You selected %s',HMF)) 

else

return;

end
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas for your quick response. It worked! :)

One more quick question.Is it possible to store the file name as a variable or something so that I can use that in another function?For example, I'm using GUI with 2 push buttons.The first push button is the question I asked above and the 2nd push button,I want to display a figure window with a result table and mentioning the file name as well.

Thanks.

Comment: @AbdusSolehinShaari: In a GUI, you can write `handles.fileName=HMF; guidata(hObject,handles);`. Then you can, in the other callback get the filename as `handles.fileName`.

Comment: Thanks again @Jonas.but i still can't display the file name in a table.I have a figure and a table inside the figure.see my codes below.Thanks.


`
f = figure;
dat = [handles.filename;AveModulus;StdDev;threshold;N]; 
rnames = {'Filename','Average Modulus (Pa)','Standard deviation (Pa)','Threshold','No of pixels for particle'};
 
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',[],... 
            'RowName',rnames,'Position',[100 200 360 120]);
`

Comment: @AbdusSolehinShaari: you may want to create a new question with this issue.